# React Native Animated.timing() multiple animations

Tags: react-native, animation, react-animated

I have an animation that uses Animated.timing() which slides a component in to view when the condition `mapIsCentered = true`. When the condition isn't met the component just disappears ungracefully. I'd like for it to slide in and out as the condition changes.

One thing to note the `mapIsCentered` state is updated on a different screen and passed as a prop to the component I am working in. I have logged the state and it updates when the map is moved.

** the slide in works as expected

Thanks to @Ashwith for the first answer

```
  const values = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 120 })).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(values, {
      toValue: mapIsCentered ? { x: 0, y: 0 } : { x: 0, y: 120 },
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  }, [mapIsCentered]);
```

```
        {!walkInProgress && !hasOnGoingWalks && (
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              transform: [{ translateY: values.y }],
            }}
          >
            <WeatherToast
              translations={translations}
              loading={loading}
              weather={weather}
            />
          </Animated.View>
```

[image: https://media.giphy.com/media/dy4oXrQU90JIpjpssb/giphy.gif]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does you animation should change when hasOnGoingWalks, walkInProgress change ??

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the structure hope it works for you...

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/excited-orange

App.js

```
const walkInProgress = false , hasOnGoingWalks = false;

export default function App() {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const [mapCentered, setMapCentered] = React.useState(false)

  const toggle = () => {
    setMapCentered((ct) => !ct);
  };
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WeatherToast mapCentered={mapCentered && !walkInProgress && !hasOnGoingWalks} />
      <Button title="shift" onPress={toggle} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

WeatherTost.js

```
export default ({ mapCentered }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(mapCentered);
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  const values = React.useRef(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 120 })).current;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mapCentered) {
      setVisible(true);
      Animated.timing(values, {
        toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        duration: 300,
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.timing(values, {
        toValue: { x: width, y: 0 },
        duration: 300,
      }).start(({ finished }) => {
        if (finished) {
          setVisible(false);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [mapCentered]);

  const styles = [];

  return visible ? (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        transform: [
          {
            translateX: values.x,
          },
          {
            translateY: values.y,
          },
        ],
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    <View />
  );
};
```

Comment: Hey @Ashwith Saldanha thank you for your response and you code works great obviously but not for my particular needs. I have used pieces of your code and will update my question as well after running in to the same issue. I hope you can help with my updated issue. Thanks!